# Converting object of array values into array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js

Cant seem to find any threads that talk about this type of data structure manipulation.

I have a new API schema for a service that I am replacing. The original API returned an array of objects.

```
[
{name: 'Conner', age: 24, gender: 'male'},
{name: 'Bryan', age: 32, gender: 'male'}
]
```

The new response looks like..

```
{
fields: {
            name: {
                values: [
                    'Conner',
                    'Bryan'
                ]
            },
            age: {
                values: [
                    24,
                    32
                ]
            },
            gender: {
                values: [
                    'male',
                    'male'
                ]
            }
        }
}
```

What would be the best/most minimal way to transform the response to the existing format: an array of objects. I can use vanilla javascript or Lodash.

Comment: `Array.map()` maybe?

Comment: Why? I dont see any usecase for this

Comment: This is a very peculiar data structure you have here. For one, how would you know how many people are there? Take the `length` of the `values` of the name prop?

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides No matter what, all value arrays with have the same length. It is peculiar. Not sure what the reasoning for the design is, not my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made it tick like you want it to by taking the `length` of the `values` of the `name` prop, in order to determine how many iterations/people we have.

Still, this is a very peculiar data set - but here goes:

```js
const fields =  {
  name: {
    values: [
      'Conner',
      'Bryan'
    ]
  },
  age: {
    values: [
      24,
      32
    ]
  },
  gender: {
    values: [
      'male',
      'male'
    ]
  }
}

const previous = fields.name.values.map((item, i) => {
  return Object.keys(fields).reduce((obj, key) => {
    obj[key] = fields[key].values[i]

    return obj
  }, {})
})

console.log(previous)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. A short map function that would transform it without explicating using property names. Thanks Nicholas.

Comment: Perhaps they are doing this to make the response smaller in size; this dataset doesn't duplicate property names for each entry. Anyway - glad it works.